# Apache Curator failing to reset expired session (Apache Curator 4.2.0; Apache Zookeeper 3.4.0)

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-curator, expired-sessions

I asked a similar question with reference to older versions of Apache Curator and Zookeeper ([Apache Curator failing to reset expired session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62183589/apache-curator-failing-to-reset-expired-session)), and was recommended to upgrade.  I've now updated to more recent versions of the client software and am seeing a very similar issue.

It appears that when a Zookeeper session is expired, there are some situations in which the client-side connection does not get reset.  This leads to the Curator client going into an exponential back-off whereby it repeatedly attempts to use the expired session, failing each time with the exception "***org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$SessionExpiredException: KeeperErrorCode = Session expired for /zk/path***".

Everything returns to being fine if the client service is completely restarted.

**Client logging** (Apache Curator 4.2.0; Apache Zookeeper 3.4.8):

```
2020-08-17 16:25:47.521 [main-SendThread(hostname:2181)] [INFO ] [org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn         ] - Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 6037ms for sessionid 0x10003f181c10087, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
2020-08-17 16:25:50.848 [main-SendThread(hostname:2181)] [INFO ] [org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn         ] - Opening socket connection to server hostname:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2020-08-17 16:25:50.848 [main-SendThread(hostname:2181)] [INFO ] [org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn         ] - Socket connection established to hostname:2181, initiating session
2020-08-17 16:25:50.851 [main-SendThread(hostname:2181)] [DEBUG] [org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn         ] - Session establishment request sent on hostname:2181
2020-08-17 16:25:50.853 [main-SendThread(hostname:2181)] [TRACE] [org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocket   ] - readConnectResult 37 0x[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,]
2020-08-17 16:25:50.853 [main-SendThread(hostname:2181)] [WARN ] [org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn         ] - Unable to reconnect to ZooKeeper service, session 0x10003f181c10087 has expired
2020-08-17 16:25:50.853 [main-SendThread(hostname:2181)] [INFO ] [org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn         ] - Unable to reconnect to ZooKeeper service, session 0x10003f181c10087 has expired, closing socket connection
2020-08-17 16:25:50.962 [main-EventThread    ] [DEBUG] [org.apache.curator.RetryLoop            ] - Retry-able exception received
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$SessionExpiredException: KeeperErrorCode = Session expired for /zk/path
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:127)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:51)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.exists(ZooKeeper.java:1102)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.ExistsBuilderImpl$3.call(ExistsBuilderImpl.java:237)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.ExistsBuilderImpl$3.call(ExistsBuilderImpl.java:226)
    at org.apache.curator.RetryLoop.callWithRetry(RetryLoop.java:109)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.ExistsBuilderImpl.pathInForegroundStandard(ExistsBuilderImpl.java:223)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.ExistsBuilderImpl.pathInForeground(ExistsBuilderImpl.java:216)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.ExistsBuilderImpl.forPath(ExistsBuilderImpl.java:175)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.ExistsBuilderImpl.forPath(ExistsBuilderImpl.java:32)
        [...]
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.NamespaceWatcher.process(NamespaceWatcher.java:68)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$EventThread.processEvent(ClientCnxn.java:530)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$EventThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:505)
2020-08-17 16:25:51.054 [main-SendThread(hostname:2181)] [TRACE] [org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO] - Doing client selector close
2020-08-17 16:25:51.055 [main-SendThread(hostname:2181)] [TRACE] [org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO] - Closed client selector
2020-08-17 16:25:51.056 [main-SendThread(hostname:2181)] [TRACE] [org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn         ] - SendThread exited loop for session: 0x10003f181c10087
2020-08-17 16:25:53.991 [main-EventThread    ] [TRACE] [o.a.curator.utils.DefaultTracerDriver   ] - Counter retries-allowed: 1
2020-08-17 16:25:53.991 [main-EventThread    ] [DEBUG] [org.apache.curator.RetryLoop            ] - Retrying operation
2020-08-17 16:25:53.992 [main-EventThread    ] [DEBUG] [org.apache.curator.RetryLoop            ] - Retry-able exception received
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$SessionExpiredException: KeeperErrorCode = Session expired for /zk/path
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:127)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:51)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.exists(ZooKeeper.java:1102)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.ExistsBuilderImpl$3.call(ExistsBuilderImpl.java:237)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.ExistsBuilderImpl$3.call(ExistsBuilderImpl.java:226)
    at org.apache.curator.RetryLoop.callWithRetry(RetryLoop.java:109)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.ExistsBuilderImpl.pathInForegroundStandard(ExistsBuilderImpl.java:223)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.ExistsBuilderImpl.pathInForeground(ExistsBuilderImpl.java:216)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.ExistsBuilderImpl.forPath(ExistsBuilderImpl.java:175)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.ExistsBuilderImpl.forPath(ExistsBuilderImpl.java:32)
        [...]
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.NamespaceWatcher.process(NamespaceWatcher.java:68)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$EventThread.processEvent(ClientCnxn.java:530)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$EventThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:505)
```

**Server logging** (Zookeeper 3.4.13)

```
2020-08-17 16:25:47,519 - INFO  [SessionTracker:ZooKeeperServer@355] - Expiring session 0x10003f181c10087, timeout of 4000ms exceeded
2020-08-17 16:25:47,521 - INFO  [ProcessThread(sid:0 cport:2181)::PrepRequestProcessor@487] - Processed session termination for sessionid: 0x10003f181c10087
2020-08-17 16:25:47,522 - INFO  [SyncThread:0:NIOServerCnxn@1056] - Closed socket connection for client which had sessionid 0x10003f181c10087
2020-08-17 16:25:50,849 - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxnFactory@215] - Accepted socket connection from 
2020-08-17 16:25:50,851 - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:ZooKeeperServer@942] - Client attempting to renew session 0x10003f181c10087 at 
2020-08-17 16:25:50,852 - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:ZooKeeperServer@687] - Invalid session 0x10003f181c10087 for client, probably expired
2020-08-17 16:25:50,852 - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@1056] - Closed socket connection for client which had sessionid 0x10003f181c10087
```

There is no server logging corresponding to the "KeeperErrorCode = Session expired" client-side errors.

Would really appreciate any insight into this issue.  Thanks!

Comment: It's hard to comment from just this. A test case would help, also logging that includes Curator's output. That said, it might be this issue that was fixed in Curator 5.x: https://github.com/apache/curator/pull/357

Comment: @Randgalt Thanks for your feedback.   Unfortunately, I've not been able to reproduce the issue reliably on demand.  The Curator log level is already set to TRACE -- is there a way to get more output?  We didn't go above Curator 4.2.0 because of the need to maintain compatibility with a ZK 3.4 server as per https://curator.apache.org/zk-compatibility-34.html

Comment: I suggest opening an issue in our Jira. As a workaround catch the exception and manually close the Curator handle.